# numpy array slicing, why sometimes 2-d array and sometimes 1-d array

Tags: python, numpy

My question is about array slicing in numpy. What's the logic for the following behavior?

```
x = arange(25)
x.shape = (5, 5)
# This results in a 2-d array in which rows and columns are excerpted from x
y = x[0:2, 0:2]
# But this results in a 1-d array
y2 = x[0:2, 0]
```

I would have expected y2 to be a 2-d array which contains the values in rows 0 and 1, column 0.

Comment: It is super handy to have slices like `y2` be 1d arrays,  For example if you want to pull out each column of an array to plot it or run it through additional signal processing, ect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This follows standard Python conventions. Look at the results of these analogous expressions:

```
>>> a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> a[4]
4
>>> a[4:5]
[4]
```

As you can see, one returns *one item*, while the other returns *a list containing one item*. This is always the way python works, and numpy is just following that convention, but at a higher dimension. Whenever you pass a slice rather than an individual item, a list is returned; this is true even if there are no items in the list, either because the end index is too low, or because the starting index is too high:

```
>>> a[4:4]
[]
>>> a[6:6]
[]
```

So in all situations, passing a slice means "return a sequence (along the given dimension)," while passing an integer means "return a single item (along the given dimension)."

Answer (score 5):

You can get your expected behavior doing `x[0:2, 0:1]`, i.e. with a single item slice. But whenever a single element is selected, that dimension is collapsed. You may not like it, but if you think about it a little bit, you should realize it is the most consistent behavior: following your logic, `x[0, 0]` would be a 2d array of 1 row and 1 column, instead of the item stored at that position.

Answer (score 2):

When you access an array using a single element instead of a slice, it will collapse that dimension. For that reason, if you have

```
x = arange(25)
y = x[10]
```

You would expect `y` to be `10` and not `array([10])`.

So, if you use

```
y2 = x[0:2, 0]
print y2.shape
(2,)
```

It will collapse the second dimension. If you want to keep that second dimension, you need to access that dimension using a slice.

```
y2 = x[0:2, 0:1]
print y2.shape
(2, 1)
```